# jQuery: check if element styles have been removed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element that is set to `display:none` by default.

```
<span class="Form__Element__ValidationError error" data-f-linked-name="__field_8321" data-f-validationerror="" style="display:none"></span>
```

When a user tries to submit a form without filling in required fields, the `="display:none;"` is removed leaving only a `style` attribute like so.

```
<span class="Form__Element__ValidationError error" data-f-linked-name="__field_8321" data-f-validationerror="" style></span>
```

Notice that it only says `style` and not `style=""`.

How can I use jQuery to check for when this is the case.

I tried this:

```
if ($('.roicalculatorblock .error').css('display') !== 'none' ) {
        //do something
    }
```

But that doesn't trigger.

Comment: You could try `.is(':visible')`. I would concentrate more on the observable properties of the DOM visible to JavaScript rather than what's shown in the Elements panel of the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below script , **if add style='display:block' property the execute if condition.**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 if( $('p').is(':visible'))
 {
   alert("currently add display block property");
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions so far. I ended up solving it somewhat differently.

```
if ( $(".roicalculatorblock").find(".ValidationFail").length > 0 ) { //do something };
```